# Pubnub and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pubnub

I'm following a twitter tutorial for a class project and I'm stuck at the part where the tutorial is using PUBNUB. I'm getting the following error:

```
Showing C:/RubyProjects/twitter/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #93 raised:

**wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)**

Extracted source (around line #93):

           PUBNUB.subscribe({
           channel  : "<%= Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(current_user.username, current_user.created_at) %>",
           callback : function(message) { updateTimeline(message) }
```

I found on stackoverflow and found that EventMachine helped some folks and I tried that but still nada :(

I checked the PUBNUB page on Github and saw that it has changed the way **channel** and **callback** was written so I tried doing that but it did not help either. Im still getting the same error about wrong number of arguments(1 for 0).

Notify.rb

```
class Notify

  def self.deliver_message_to_user(params)
    post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    user.channel ||= Channel.new(
        :channel_ident =>
            Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(user.username, user.created_at.to_s))
    Pubnub.publish({
                       :channel => user.channel.channel_ident,
                       :message => post.to_json(:include => :user)
                   })
  end

end
```

application.html.erb

```
<script>

        function updateTimeline(message) {
            var html = JST['post'](jQuery.parseJSON(message));
            $('#timeline').prepend(html);
        }

        Pubnub.subscribe({
            :channel  => "<%= Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(current_user.username, current_user.created_at) %>",
        :callback => function(message) { updateTimeline(message) }
        })

    </script>
```

I put **require 'digest'** in my application.rb file and it still din't help. Could it be the syntax? If it is, i'm not sure what the correct syntax would be.

Comment: hi! we are looking into this

Comment: also send us a note to support@pubnub.com and let us know if the answer below is helpful in solving the issue of `**wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)**`.

Answer (score 0):

## Publishing PubNub Messages in Ruby on Rails 4.0+

I'm pulling the following details from the PubNub Ruby README.md file - https://github.com/pubnub/ruby/blob/master/README.md

First you need to **require** PubNub lib from the PubNub Gem in Ruby.

```
## Require PubNub Gem
require 'pubnub'

## Instantiate a new PubNub instance.
pubnub = Pubnub.new(
    :publish_key   => 'demo', # publish_key only required if publishing.
    :subscribe_key => 'demo', # required
    :secret_key    => nil,    # optional, if used, message signing is enabled
    :cipher_key    => nil,    # optional, if used, encryption is enabled
    :ssl           => nil     # true or default is false
)

## Create a callback for checking response of Publish
@my_callback = lambda { |message| puts(message) }

## Execute Publish
pubnub.publish(
    :channel  => :hello_world,
    :message  => "hi",
    :callback => @my_callback
)

## Sometimes you need a sleep depending on your server type
sleep(1)
```

Comment: I just spent a good chunk of time trying to figure out why this wouldn't work. It turns out the process was ending before the publish was firing. pubnub.publish just schedules for the message to be sent on the next interval. If the ruby script ends right after scheduling it will not send the message. I fixed this by putting `sleep 1` after `pubnub.publish(...)`.